# creating pdf with solid color as background pdfmake

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation

I’m developing an app that creates pdfs automatically. Using the pdfmake, I can create the pdf easily but I can’t find anywhere how to put a background on the pdf. I found how to put images as a background but I can’t find how to put a solid color.

```
var docDefinition = {
  pageSize: 'A3',
  content: [{
    text: $globals.mural.name,
    style: 'header'
  }, {
    image: uri,
    width: size.width,
    height: size.height,
    margin: size.margin,
    alignment: 'center',
  }],
  styles: {
    header: {
      alignment: 'center',
      fontSize: '70',
      font: 'LaneNarrow',
      color: $globals.mural.layout.textColor
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now pdfMake doesn't seem to support directly adding background color to main content. For this one approach is to use the canvas method.
In doc defination you need to add

```
    background: function () {
      return {
        canvas: PdfOrderUtilities.getCanvas()
      };
    },
```

//The actual function

```
public static getCanvas() {
return [
    {
        type: 'rect',
        x: 0, y: 0, w: 600, h: 840,
        //The background color
        color: '#F4F6F9'
    }
]
```

}